# Django error with (CRUD) urls.py

Tags: django, python-2.7, crud, django-urls

as part of my continuing want to do well on my Uni course, I'm doing a bit of web-dev in Python(2.7) using Django. I had followed Django's tutorial and now I am following this tutorial. However, I get a somewhat inexplicable error when I add in the urls.py part to give me some viewing models. The project is called 'practice' and the app is called 'orders'. Within 'orders' are the models (which all validate)

The (relevant part of) urls.py is:

```
'django.views.generic.list_details',
url(r'^orders/$', 'object_list', {'queryset': 'orders.Product.objects.all()'}),
url(r'^orders(?P<slug>[-\W]+)/$', 'object_detail', {'queryset': 'orders.Product.objects.all()'})
```

I've double checked `ROOT_URLCONF` is correctly set so the error appears to be somewhere within `'django.views.generic.list_details'` as a use.

The error message is: 
`AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute resolve`

A good Google didn't seem to produce anything reasonable so any chance of a hand please guys?

Thanks!

Comment: Yep sorry, that was a typo with my question not an actual issue with the code!

Comment: Don't know if it's another typo or your problem, but loose the single quotes around `orders.Product.object.all()`.

Comment: Yeah, I tried it with and without the quote marks. Some website somewhere recommended I use it with and it continued not to work (same error message).

Comment: can you post the stack trace and a litle more context on `urls.py` ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you forget "patterns"?

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
  (r'^$', ...),
  # ...
```

Also I've noticed a slash missing:

```
url(r'^orders(?P<slug>[-\W]+)/$', 'object_detail', {'queryset': 'orders.Product.objects.all()'})
url(r'^orders/(?P<slug>[-\W]+)/$', 'object_detail', {'queryset': 'orders.Product.objects.all()'})
```

Answer (score 0):

The `AttributeError` suggests to me that the string `'django.views.generic.list_details'` is being treated as a url to be resolved. However, you've omitted too much of your `urls.py` to say for sure.

Make sure the prefix string is the *first* argument to `django.conf.urls.patterns`. If you want to break up your urls and use different prefix strings, invoke `patterns` multiple times as described in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/http/urls/#multiple-view-prefixes):

```
urlpatterns = patterns('myapp.views', 
    url(r'^$', 'app_index'), 
    url(r'^(?P<year>\d{4})/(?P<month>[a-z]{3})/$','month_display'),
) 

urlpatterns += patterns('weblog.views', 
    url(r'^tag/(?P<tag>\w+)/$', 'tag'), 
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You've quoted the value in the arguments dictionary in each pattern, so it's being treated as a string. It should be:

```
url(r'^orders/$', 'object_list', {'queryset': orders.Product.objects.all()})
```

Not that you'll need to import `orders` - except I doubt that will work, because `Product` will be defined in the models file inside orders. It would be easier to just import Product and refer to it directly.